# Boost C++ xml_oarchive Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, xml, serialization, boost

I'm very new to Boost serialization.  I'm using Boost to serialize a Xml document:

```
typedef struct xmllist
{
   std::string Name;
   int Param;

   friend class boost::serialization::access;
   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
   {
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Name);
      ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Param);
   }
} XMLLIST;

void XmlWrite()
{
   std::ofstream ofs("xmlfile.xml");
   assert(ofs.good());
   boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
   XMLLIST xmllist;
   xmllist.Name = "Name";
   xmllist.Param = 1;
   oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(xmllist);
}
```

boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs) is giving me Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'oa' was corrupted.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and boost_1_56_0.

Can someone please help me in this issue?

Comment: `typedef struct`  There is no need for this in a C++ program.  Just `struct` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion that the stack corruption happens not in the provided code but somewhere else. The slightly modified code, which I provided below, works without any error under MSVC++ 2013 and Boost 1.57. Also it works fine on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/734b3d3a751c9520).

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

struct CXMLList {
    std::string Name;
    int Param;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Name);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Param);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ostringstream ofs;
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
    CXMLList xmllist;
    xmllist.Name = "Name";
    xmllist.Param = 1;
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(xmllist);
    std::cout << "XML is:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << ofs.str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```